# Trigger.oldmap defined in insert context?

Tags: apex, trigger

I was trying to read and understand some code that a consultant wrote however i think that it is not correct....

I havent used Trigger.oldmap however after reading about it it appears to get the value from your trigger.new record.

```
 For(Opportunity OppObj: Trigger.new)
 {

 If(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
      If(OppObj.Contact__c != null)
        {
        //Do stuff
        }
      Else
      {
         If (OppObj.Contact__c == null && Trigger.oldMap.get(OppObj.Id).Contact__c != null)
         {
            //Do other Stuff
         }

      Else If (oppObj.Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Contact__c == null)
      {
            //Do something else
      }

  }
```

If I am not mistaken the first IF statement could happen if the contact look up is not null. However the else and IF conditions seems illogical where as it is stating that if the current oppt record contact is null and is not null do something. Is this True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will crash when no Contact__c is selected; Trigger.oldMap does not exist in an "insert" operation (there are no "old" values from the database). Instead, it should be outside the top-level if statement entirely:

```
For(Opportunity OppObj: Trigger.new) {
    If(Trigger.isInsert) {
        If(OppObj.Contact__c != null) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    } Else { // Not an insert operation
        If (OppObj.Contact__c == null && Trigger.oldMap.get(OppObj.Id).Contact__c != null) {
        //Do other Stuff
        } Else If (oppObj.Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Contact__c == null) {
        //Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The indentation and brace style of this code makes it harder to follow than it should be. Here's what this could look like with a *slightly* more reasonable code style.

```
for (Opportunity oppObj : Trigger.new) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        if (oppObj.Contact__c != null) {
            // Do stuff. This is Condition (1).
        } else {
            if (oppObj.Contact__c == null 
                && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Contact__c != null) {
                // Do other stuff. This is Condition (2).
            } else if (oppObj.Contact__c != null 
                       && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Contact__c == null) {
                // Do something else. This is Condition (3), which cannot execute.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is expressing three conditions:

1. The `Contact__c` lookup is currently non-blank, in the record as updated by whatever fired this trigger.
2. The `Contact__c` lookup is currently blank, but used to be non-blank. That's what `oldMap` does - it allows you to access the value before the trigger change.
3. The `Contact__c` lookup is currently non-blank, but used to be blank.

Condition (3) , the bottom `else if`, will never execute, because it's contained in an `else` block of the primary `if` that leads to Condition (1), which will be `true` in any circumstance where Condition (3) could also be `true`. Conditions (2) and (3) will never be evaluated if `Contact__c` is not `null`.

It's hard to proscribe a remedy without knowing what this code is supposed to do, but it looks to me like Conditions (2) and (3) should likely be outside the `else` block.

Comment: ok, so if contact__c used to be blank how does that handle insert that sounds like you would only get that value on update. (Also thanks for the style tip. I came from .Net so that was easiest. The consultant didnt have any indentation or style. )

Comment: You will only get it on update. See sfdcfox's answer; I actually didn't notice that the trigger event was implied.