# Trigger after insert throwing null exception

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

The code is pretty self explantory, I'm trying to sendEmail if the status is changed to `Closed`

Getting the null exception when I'm trying to insert a new record and it does work fine with the updating the record and I know why the error is throwing it's because when you inserting the new record the oldMap is null, so my question how would you handle this situation?

```
trigger ServiceRequestEmail on Service_Request__c (after insert, after update) {
      if(Trigger.isAfter){
           if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
              ServiceRequestEmailHandler.sendSingleEmail(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
           }
      }
}
```

TriggerHandler:

```
public static void sendSingleEmail(List<Service_Request__c> newList, Map<Id, Service_Request__c> oldMap){
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
     for(Service_Request__c sr : newList){
         Service_Request__c oldServiceRequest = oldMap.get(sr.Id); //ERROR null
         //Service_Request__c newServiceRequest = newMap.get(serviceRequestId);

         if(sr.Status__c == 'Closed' && sr.Status__c != oldServiceRequest.Status__c ){
                //build message email message but don't send
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                //add relevant info/fields
                mailToSend.add(mail);
         }
    }  

    Messaging.sendEmail(mailToSend);
}
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220200/trigger-oldmap-defined-in-insert-context

Answer (score 0):

Your `oldMap` is `null` in the `after insert` context. Typically, I would recommend you just use a filtering library (such as Bluewolf's Selector), but it is straightforward to roll your own also. The core recommendation is you should split out your filtering logic into separate methods.

```
public static List<MyObject> shouldSendEmail(List<MyObject> newRecords)
{
    List<MyObject> output = new List<MyObject>();
    for (MyObject newRecord : newRecords)
        if (/*insert condition*/)
            output.add(newRecord);
    return output;
}
public static List<MyObject> shouldSendEmail(List<MyObject> newRecords, Map<Id, MyObject> oldRecords)
{
    List<MyObject> output = new List<MyObject>();
    for (MyObject newRecord : newRecords)
        if (/*update condition*/)
            output.add(newRecord);
    return output;
}
```

This pattern scales extremely well even up to a large number of filters and/or high level of complexity. You can easily take it a step further by making the logic inside your `if` conditions separate methods also.

Comment: yes I did mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Bluewolf's Selector? interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think Adrian's answer is the best way to handle such issues, anyway in this specific case you could leverage [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) (`?.`)  to avoid the NPE.
This operator returns null instead of throwing a NullPointerException.

```java
public static void sendSingleEmail(List<Service_Request__c> newList, Map<Id, Service_Request__c> oldMap){
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Service_Request__c sr : newList){
        Service_Request__c oldServiceRequest = oldMap?.get(sr.Id); // No more NPE due to Safe Navigation Operator
        //Service_Request__c newServiceRequest = newMap.get(serviceRequestId);

        if(sr.Status__c == 'Closed' && sr.Status__c != oldServiceRequest?.Status__c ){ // You have to use SNO here too
            //build message email message but don't send
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            //add relevant info/fields
            mailToSend.add(mail);
        }
    }

    Messaging.sendEmail(mailToSend);
}
```